# find the number of neighbour pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I create an image, which has random groups of random pixels:

```
img=ones(100,100)
numRandom = 505;
linearIndices = ceil(numel(img) * rand(1, numRandom));
img(linearIndices) = 0;
imshow(img)`
```

Then I turn this image into binary and find the area of each group of pixels with:

```
regionprops(L, 'Area');
```

I also need the perimeter of each group. Unfortunately, `regionprops` doesn't give me correct results (for example, if there is one pixel the function returns 0 instead of 4), so I think that it is better to find number of neighbour pixels of each group (so that for the case of only one pixel the answer will be 4). If the group is on the border of the image it should also be taken into consideration.

Can anybody give me a tip about how to do it?

Comment: not related to your question, why won't you use `randi` instead of `rand` and avoid the need of `ciel`?

Answer (score 1):

`Perimeter` and `regionprops` is not what you need then, or find all these single pixels using `regionprops(L, 'Area')==1` and set their perimeter to 4....

From Matlab documentation:

`Perimeter` — is the distance around the boundary of the region. regionprops computes the perimeter by calculating **the distance between each adjoining pair of pixels** around the border of the region. **If the image contains discontiguous regions, regionprops returns unexpected results**. The following figure shows the pixels included in the perimeter calculation for this object.

[image]

From this image you can see that the edge pixels are counted only once, not twice.

Comment: of course I can change to 4. but it will work only for one pixel. and what if there is an element consisting of several pixels?